# Background worker is not reporting progress Winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a background worker running, which is dynamically making form fields from an xml file. Depending on the size of the xml, it takes some time to load, so I am using a loading bar to report the progress to use so they won't exit out of the program. The program works as intended, it hides the loading panel and shows the form fields when the worker finishes, but while loading, the loading bar won't load. I received no errors.

This is where the report progress is being called:

```
                if (!retrievePath.Equals(""))
                {
                    // create the template with the data from the file
                    XDocument filledDoc = templateCreator.CreateTemplateWithGivenData2(retrievePath, fileName2);
                    tempDoc = filledDoc;
                    XElement root = tempDoc.Root;
                    // get child forms of return data state and sections
                    IDataInterface dataInterface = new DataInterfaceImplementation();
                    IEnumerable<XElement> sections = dataInterface.GetSections(filledDoc);
                    // Grab forms that aren't empty
                    IEnumerable<XElement> forms = XmlClass.GetMefForms(filledDoc).Where(u => u.Value != "").ToList();
                    IEnumerable<XElement> extra = dataInterface.GetSections(filledDoc).Where(u => u.Value != "").ToList();
                    // get the return header state
                    elemForms = dataMiddleman.GetSections(filledDoc);

                    foreach (XElement el in elemForms)
                    {
                        if (el.Name.LocalName.Equals("ReturnHeaderState"))
                        {
                            createForms(el, 3);
                        }
                    }
                    foreach (XElement el in forms)
                    {
                        i = i + 1;
                        i = (i / forms.Count()) * 100;
                        if (i == 100)
                        {
                            i = (i / (forms.Count() - 1)) * 100;
                        }
                        createForms(el, i);
                    }
        private void createForms(XElement x, int i)
    {
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);
            var pLabel = new ParentLabel(x);
            this.leftGroup.Controls.Add(pLabel);
            var parentPanel = new CustomPanel(x);
            parentPanel.SendToBack();
            this.thebox.Controls.Add(parentPanel);
            RecursiveTraverse(x, parentPanel);
            pLabel.Click += (sender, e) => PLabel_Click(sender, e);
            pPanels.Add(parentPanel);
        });
    }
```

This is my background worker code:

```
    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        loadingPanel.BringToFront();
        populateNewFields();
    }
    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        loadingBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }
    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        loadingBar.Value = 100;
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        loadingPanel.SendToBack();
        loadingBar.Value = 0;
    }
```

Comment: Why invoke the BackGroundWorked1 Control in a Delegate ` `this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);`

Comment: The UI thread is burning 100% core once background execution progressed to the createForms() calls and the code starts calling ReportProgress().  Having no meaningful way to measure progress is not unusual, you then have to resort to Style = Marquee.

Comment: Have you set WorkerReportsProgress = true ?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is about **Background worker is not reporting progress Winforms** and I hope it's ok if I use a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to demo how to successfully fire an `event` when progress occurs on the background thread (which is is one way to achieve the outcome you want) and reducing the complex Xml operations to a "time-consuming black box" to be dealt with as a separate issue.

This `Form` will provide a means to test the notification using the `MockCreateForm` method which mimics a form creation by blocking the background worker for 5 ms. I believe your design spec is to send a notification every 100 operations.

[image: Worker idle]

Generic `event` lacks the needed properties so inherit `EventArgs` to customize the info received (declaring it outside the `MainForm` class).

```
public delegate void ProgressEventHandler(ProgressEventArgs e);
public class ProgressEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public ProgressEventArgs(int count, int total)
    {
        Count = count;
        Total = total;
    }
    public int Count { get; }
    public int Total { get; }
}
```

When the button (actually a `CheckBox` where `Appearance`=`Button`) state is toggled, it calls this worker `Task` using a `CancellationTokenSource` and `CancellationToken` so it can be halted. Every 100 times, the `Progress` `event` is fired:

```
private void btnWorker_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(btnWorker.Checked)
    {
        _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        Task.Run(() => 
        {
            var formCount = 10000;
            for (int i = 0; i < formCount; i++)
            {
                if(_cts.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    return;
                }
                // Notify every 100 times.
                if((i % 100) == 0)
                {
                    Progress?.Invoke(new ProgressEventArgs(count: i, total: formCount));
                }
                MockCreateForm();
            }
            Progress?.Invoke(new ProgressEventArgs(count: formCount, total: formCount));
        }, _cts.Token);
    }
    else
    {
        _cts.Cancel();
        labelStatus.Text = "Idle";
    }
}
CancellationTokenSource _cts = null;
```

The only thing left is to consume the event in the `MainForm`. The *only* thing that needs to be marshalled back onto the UI thread is the brief moment that `Label.Text` is being updated.

```
public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Progress += (e) =>
    {
        Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate 
        {
            labelStatus.Text = $"{e.Count} of {e.Total}";
        });
    };
}
public event ProgressEventHandler Progress;
```

[image: Updates]

*What* you do on the background thread is up to you. Just put it here:

```
public void MockCreateForm()
{
    Task.Delay(5).Wait();
}
```

I hope this gets you closer to what you are trying to achieve.